# How to call a function inside a movieclip from the main timeline in AS3?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, scope, movieclip

I have a movieclip named `clip1` and I would like to call a function inside it named `myFunction()`  from the main timeline itself. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clip1.myFunction();
```

It's simple as that

If a function has any arguments then

```
clip1.myFunction(arg1, arg2...);
```